# How to update data between multiple observeEvents with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

How can I reuse the data processed by observeEvent in another observeEvent?

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

dataset <- diamonds
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      actionButton("read", "read_diamonds"),
      
      pickerInput('filter1',
                  'clarity_Filter1',
                  choices=c(""),
                  multiple  =  TRUE,
                  options = list(actionsBox=TRUE,liveSearch=TRUE),
                  ),
      
      sliderInput('filter2','table_Filter2', min=0, max=100, value=c(0, 100))
      
      ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("display"),
    ),

    )
  )
  )
```

```
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Initial setting
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    
    diamond_df <- diamonds

    #filter1 update
    clarity_choise <- as.vector(unique(diamond_df$clarity))
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "clarity_Filter1",
      choices = clarity_choise,
      selected = clarity_choise,
      options = list(
        actionsBox  =  TRUE,
        liveSearch = TRUE
      ),
    )
    
    #filter2 update
    max_value <- max(as.numeric((diamond_df$table)))
    min_value <- min(as.numeric((diamond_df$table)))
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "nega_char_slier",
      max = max_value ,
      min = min_value ,
      value = c(min,max)
    )
        
    #display
    output$display = renderDataTable(diamond_df,options= list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 20), pageLength = 5))
    
    
  })
  
  #What to do if filter1,2 is updated
  observeEvent(c(input$filter1,
                 input$filter2),{
    
    #data update
    diamond_df <- diamond_df %>% filter(clarity %in% input$filter1)
    diamond_df <- diamond_df %>% filter(input$filter2[1]<table & input$filter2[2]>table)
    
    #display
    output$display = renderDataTable(diamond_df,options= list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 20), pageLength = 5))
    
    })
  }
```

What you want to do with the sample code

1. Press "read" to read diamonds and update clarity and table. Display the data table.
2. Update filter1 and filter2 for the data read in 1. The data is also updated and the data table is displayed.

However, because the scope of 1 and the scope of 2 are different, there is no data and an error occurs.

> Warning: Error in filter: object'diamond_df' not found

What should I do in such a case?

Comment: You should use `reactiveValues` object to pass the data between `observeEvents`.  Also, what is `input$file`?  It is not defined in the ui.

Comment: Also, `output$display` should be defined only once, and it can be defined outside the observer once you have a `reactiveValues` object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I heard reactive Values ​​for the first time. How do you use it?
input$file is a mistake in input$read.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use reactiveValues object as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

dataset <- diamonds
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      actionButton("read", "read_diamonds"),
      
      pickerInput('filter1',
                  'clarity_Filter1',
                  choices=c(""),
                  multiple  =  TRUE,
                  options = list(actionsBox=TRUE,liveSearch=TRUE),
      ),
      
      sliderInput('filter2','table_Filter2', min=0, max=100, value=c(10, 100))
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("display")
    )
    
  )
)
)

#server.r

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  diamond <- reactiveValues( df=NULL )
  
  ###Initial setting
  observe({diamond$df <- diamonds})
  
  observeEvent(input$read, {
  
    
    df1 <- diamonds
    
    #filter1 update
    clarity_choise <- as.vector(unique(df1$clarity))
    
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "filter1",
      choices = clarity_choise,
      selected = clarity_choise,
      options = list(
        actionsBox  =  TRUE,
        liveSearch = TRUE
      ),
    )

    #filter2 update
    max_value <- max(as.numeric(df1$table))
    min_value <- min(as.numeric(df1$table))
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "filter2",
      max = max_value ,
      min = min_value ,
      value = c(min_value,max_value)
    )
    
  })
  
  #display
  output$display = renderDT(datatable(diamond$df),options= list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 20), pageLength = 5))
  
  #What to do if filter1,2 is updated
  observeEvent(c(input$filter1,
                 input$filter2),{
                   
                   #data update
                   if (is.null(input$filter1)) {
                     diamond$df <- diamonds %>% 
                            dplyr::filter( input$filter2[1]<table & input$filter2[2]>table)
                   }else{
                     diamond$df <- diamonds %>% dplyr::filter(clarity %in% input$filter1) %>% 
                       dplyr::filter( input$filter2[1]<table & input$filter2[2]>table)
                   } 
                   
                 }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for writing the code.Let me ask you two questions.
1: `observe ({diamond$df <-diamonds})`  What is this doing?
2: It is the part of `observeEvent (input $ read)`, but it is assigned to `df1` as `df1<-diamonds`. Shouldn't I use `diamond$df`? For example   `clarity_choise <-as.vector (unique (df1$clarity))`  Instead, like `clarity_choise <-as.vector (unique (diamond $ df $ clarity))`.

Comment: 1. In the real use case, you could be assigning a reactive object to `diamond$df`.  2.  Good question. If you do `df1 <- diamond$df`, then once you subset you cannot get back to original data unless you have a reset button to reassign as `diamond$df <- diamonds`.  Try it.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. If possible, I'll ask another related question. I would be happy if you could see it if you can afford it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080821/in-shinyapp-observeevent-is-executed-without-permission